# I would like to know more about functioning of this part of code

Tags: java

There is a problem in [SPOJ](http://www.spoj.com/problems/COINS) for that I was searching other extra inputs to understand the problem. I came across the below code, they say they used memozation. I could not able to understand the use of Array, can anybody explain the code? I want to develop my own logic and use it.

```
  import java.util.Scanner;

     class Coins {
     long r[] = new long[1000000];

      public long Coin(long n) {
        if (n == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (n < 12) {
            return n;
        }

        if (n < 1000000) {
            if (r[(int) n] > 0) {
                return r[(int) n];
            }
        }

        long m = Math.max(n, Coin(n / 2) + Coin(n / 3) + Coin(n / 4));

        if (n < 1000000) {
            r[(int) n] = m;
            return m;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (sc.hasNextLong()) {
            long n = sc.nextLong();
            Coins i = new Coins();
            long r = i.Coin(n);
            System.out.println(r);
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: can you format your code?

Comment: Which part(s) exactly are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: the function coin called multiple times and what the array does ?

Comment: Please read this help page before you try to format your code (your last edit made it much worse): http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array is used as an internal cache. It buffers the result of `Math.max(n, Coin(n / 2) + Coin(n / 3) + Coin(n / 4))` for "small" inputs (`< 1000000`) of `n`. This avoids re-computation of the result if the same input parameter is used multiple times.

For tiny values (`0 <= n < 12`) no complex computation is required and the cache in not used. For all other "small" values of `n`, the cache is checked if it contains the result already. It is known that zero indicates an empty/non-valid cache entry. Recall, that Java initializes all array entries with zero and `m` cannot be zero either. Thus, if there is a valid entry in the cache, this value is just returned as result:

```
if (n < 1000000) {
    if (r[(int) n] > 0)
        return r[(int) n];
}
```

Otherwise, the return value is computed: `long m = ...`. Finally, for small values of `n` the result is additionally buffered in the cache.

```
if (n < 1000000)
    r[(int) n] = m;
```